# Decoding Error by Base64 Usage

Tags: perl, base64

I have some troubles with decoding an encoded file with base64.

I use this command to encode an XML file within a script:

```
base64 $file_path | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'
```

And it works fine.

But when I try to decode it with this command:

```
base64 -d "encodedfile" > "decodedfile"
```

I get an error. It just decodes till a specific point and then interrupt the decoding process. It seems that I have an illegal character in the encoded file but I cant't explain why.

Have someone of you any idea?

greetings

Comment: Try the `--noerrcheck` option.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Seems logical but -n or --noerrcheck is an unnkown options. I wonder why.

Comment: How can you say that encoding works fine when you cannot decode the stuff afterwards? Why are you running the regular expression over the output of `base64`?

Comment: I wasn't really clear yesterday.

I had to make the regular expression because of indexing the file in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing funky stuff to your base64 after encoding, you should do the reverse funky stuff before decoding:

```
perl -pe 's/\\n/\n/g' "encodedfile" | base64 -d
```